# How to conditionally initialize values in form using Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using the Formik library in my React project. In my formik form, I want to initial values conditionally. If it is insert operation than I want to set the first value of drop-down as the default value and if it is update operation, I want to assign the values from the react state.

Below is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data:{
          studentId : ''
        }
     }
 };

render() {

   const studentList = this.props.studentList && this.props.studentList;

          <Formik
             initialValues={this.state.data}
             enableReinitialize={true}
             onSubmit={this.formSubmit}
          >
          {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
            <Field component={Select} name="studentId"
                   options={studentList}
                   value={studentList.filter(option => option.value == values.studentId)}
                   onChange={(opt) => {
                                        setFieldValue("studentId", opt.value);
                                      }}                                            
             />
          )}
          </Formik>

}
```

Now, if it is insert operation, student id should be set as the first record from the student list and if it is update operation, studentId will already be present in this.state.data; I have taken a variable that denotes the operation type. so I do not have to worry about knowing the current operation type. I tried calling function inside  initialValues of formik but that didn't work. I can not set state inside render, that will result into continuous loop. So how can I achieve this in formik.?